# make oracle apex menu items collapsed by default, currently expanded by default in oracle apex 20.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

When the app open the expandable menu items in the navigation are expanded by default. I want to make them collapsed by default. Is there any option to do it or should I make custom js or plsql code to do it..?

Answer (score 1):

Shared Components > User Interface Attributes > Navigation Menu. If you uncheck "Use Template Defaults", you have the option to check/uncheck "Collapsed by Default"

Comment: Works like a charm for me but I'm on 20.1

Comment: Has the app been created in 20.1 or in a previous release? If it has been created in a previous release you will have to refresh the Universal Theme (Shared Components -> Themes)

Comment: @PatrickWolf The app is created in 20.1 dear... Those settings are by default selected as collapsed. But in UI its expanded. :(